# Clear interval from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger a `setInterval()` based on a success of a particular function.

```
function myCountComplete(){
   //do something
   count++;
   if(count > 10){
      var myVar = setInterval(function(){ setColor() }, 300);
   }
}

function setColor() {
    var x = document.body;
    x.style.backgroundColor = x.style.backgroundColor == "yellow" ? "pink" : "yellow";
}
```

How can I clear the `myVar` interval when a button is clicked?

```
$("#stop").click(function(){
    clearInterval(myVar);
});
```

Comment: Have `myVar` as a global variable. ie declare it (`var myVar`) outside of the functions.

Answer (score 13):

You can always set it on the global scope, i.e.

```
window.myTimer = setInterval(function(){ setColor() }, 300);

$("#stop").click(function(){
    clearInterval(window.myTimer);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

"window" is not necessary, and my opinion is that is bad practice to use it. 
Just remove "var" and scope will be automatically global.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: Thanks. yes, I prefer @andy 's answer.

Comment: your answer work is it good practise for not using `var, let, const` in this scenrio?

Answer (score 1):

This is a scope issue.
See [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Basically,
declare the `myVar` into a scope available in both case. For instance:

```
function myCountComplete(){
//do something
count++;
if(count > 10){
   window.myVar = setInterval(function(){ setColor() }, 300);
}
}

$("#stop").click(function(){
    clearInterval(window.myVar);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue so I just moved the `setInterval` to a global scope and added a check to it so that whatever code that was to be implemented in each interval would only be implemented if the check is successful, else the interval would do nothing.

```
const someInterval = setInterval(() => {
  if (checkSuccessful) {
    // Do something.
  }
  // Do nothing.
}, 1000);

clearInterval(someInterval);
```